# Minted Listings don't behave the way they should

Tags: captions, highlighting, minted

I'm quite new to `La/TeX` and I have a question about the package `minted` and it's listing feature.

I'm using a `LaTeX` template from someone else who gave it to me. He used the listing feature as well but the output in his case isn't the way I want it to be.

This is what it looks like

[image: what it look like]

This is the what I want it to look like (except for the red rectangle)

[image: what it should look like]

I want the listing caption to look the default `LaTeX` way plus I don't want all the frames and stuff.

Here's the code I used:

```
    \begin{listing}[H]  
    \begin{minted}{cpp}
    #include <string>
    int main(){
    // Example comment
    ExampleNamespace::object* stuff;
    int e, x, a, m, p, l, e=0;
    double d = 3.0;
    string i = "donno"; 
    stuff->setSomeMoreStuff("stuff");
    // bring it to an end
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Stuff doing stuff (C++)}
    \label{lst:Stuff}
    \end{listing}
```

to produce the first listing I included it in my main.tex. The problem is I don't know what causes this listing appearance. So I deleted everything that was `minted`-related and differed from the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086366/change-latex-minted-listings-numbering-to-include-current-section%22this%22) template. BUT WHATEVER I DO after compiling main.tex THE OUTPUT STAYS THE SAME.

The second listing is made by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086366/change-latex-minted-listings-numbering-to-include-current-section%22this%22) (same this-link as above) template.

in order to find stuff in the main.tex I can delete, I searched for 'minted' 'mint' 'listing' and so on ...
this is what I deleted in my main.tex (I don't know what it did/what it was for):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minted@write@detok}[1]{%
 \immediate\write\FV@OutFile{\detokenize{#1}}}%

\newcommand{\minted@FVB@VerbatimOut}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \FV@UseKeyValues
    \FV@DefineWhiteSpace
    \def\FV@Space{\space}%
    \FV@DefineTabOut
    %\def\FV@ProcessLine{\immediate\write\FV@OutFile}% %Old, non-Unicode version
    \let\FV@ProcessLine\minted@write@detok %Patch for Unicode
    \immediate\openout\FV@OutFile #1\relax
    \let\FV@FontScanPrep\relax
% DG/SR modification begin - May. 18, 1998 (to avoid problems with ligatures)
    \let\@noligs\relax
% DG/SR modification end
    \FV@Scan}
    \let\FVB@VerbatimOut\minted@FVB@VerbatimOut

\renewcommand\minted@savecode[1]{
  \immediate\openout\minted@code\jobname.pyg
  \immediate\write\minted@code{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}%
  \immediate\closeout\minted@code}
\makeatother
```

Like L said THE OUTPUT STAYED THE SAME!

I use the Texmaker editor and I compile with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|biber %.bcf|makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls|pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|evince %.pdf
```

I wonder whether there is any package included in the main.tex (there are a lot included) that causes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsTks.png) behaviour.

Maybe my `LaTeX` setup saved [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsTks.png) style after first compiling and if I change something afterwards and recompile it the compiler doesn't care...

Btw, sorry my bad english...
If there's anything you don't understand let me know.

Comment: Hi, I think you should stop copy-pasting together some stuff that you don't understand, and build up your code step by step. Also please post an MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: hi, that's what i usually do (building up code step by step) but since there are deadlines in every project and i'm totally new to latex i tried to save time and still have a nice output. like i said the actual main.tex is way to big to post it here and to produce the second figure you simply have to append the given code to the document-template under the link i gave. But that wouldn't make any sense since i know that it works that way. i want to know why it doesn't work in my main.tex ... what reasons you think might be fitting. my english is sooo bad! sorry

Comment: for instance, what does the \savecode command do? i mean could it be possible that minted saves the style-settings to jobname.pyg and then when recompiling reads them from that file instead of locking what's given in the main.tex?

Comment: Or do you know any package that produces the kind of output in figure 1. ? so i can look it up and exclude it.

Comment: The `minted` float `listings` doesn't add frames or whatever as standard. We will need a MWE to help here: please try to put one together. `minted` will add lines with a setting such as `\begin{minted}[frame = lines]{cpp}` or the equivalent global setting (look for `\newminted`, perhaps).